# DatagridTextColumn Multibinding from two different sources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multibinding

I have a DataGrid whos itemsource is set to observable collection called sorties

One of the columns called 'Location' needs to be multibound. Essentially the value in the cell input is an ID and the output needs to be a name. The multibinder would take the ID and another collection of locations and find the name to return.

For example

WPF

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="ICAO">
      <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ICAOIDConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="TakeoffLocationID"/>
                    <Binding Path="Locations*" />
           </MultiBinding>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Converter

```
 public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Debug.Print(values[0].GetType().Name.ToString());
        Debug.Print(values[1].GetType().Name.ToString());
        int id = (int)values[0];
        ObservableCollection<Location> locs = values[1] as ObservableCollection<Location>;

        try
        {
            Location l = locs.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return l.ICAO;
        }
        catch { return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; }
    }
```

Here is my issue. My datagrid's item source is set to a "Sorties" class collection. In this collection exist the 'TakeoffLocationID' path for the first bind, but the 'Locations' path does not exist in this class to use in my second bind. It exists, and is populated from a different itemsource. I don't want to attach a list of locations to every sortie as that is not memory efficient.

How can I tap into an itemsource that is different from my grids source. I have looked at creating static and dynamic resources, but can't figure out how to populate and use them with my list of 600 locations that are pulled from a database.

Feel free to ask for clarification. I am having a hard time explaining this question.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can probably use `{Binding DataContext.Locations, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}` -- that ought to get you to the main viewmodel

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's exactly what I was trying to figure out how to do. I will try this when I get to work tomorrow. Hopefully it works. So many ways to bind it's hard to keep up. Thank you.